# Why I have not the option to open the web Inspector interface - Safari?

Tags: network, safari

I want to open this interface to look the source code or response, like below:

[image]

But, when I want to open the `localhost:8080/xxx`'s page, I found I do not able to open that, it is gray:

[image]

So, how to resolve it in Safari?

Comment: Pro tip: if you want to show screenshots with english version of the Safari, you can type this in Terminal: `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari -AppleLanguages '(en)'`.

Comment: @Mateusz Szlosek, now I have updated my post, so review it.

Comment: Can You show us what is the "source" of the html file you want to inspect? I mean content of the file you want to open.

Comment: @Mateusz Szlosek, it is a `Servlet` page, and maybe it has no html contents here. But I use firefox can open the `Web Inspector`.

Comment: What is shown when you Secondary/Right click on a page and select **Inspect Element**?

Comment: @Mateusz Szlosek, great, I right click the page, and select **Review the elements**, it shows the interface, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another way of showing the Web Inspector.

Right/Secondary click on a web page and select: **Inspect Element** or **Review the elements**.

Comment: I don't see that option in the rightclick menu.

Comment: @Pacerier You prob ably have to enable Developer Menu in Preferences. It in "Preferences" -> "Advanced" -> "Show Develop menu in menu bar"

Answer (score 0):

The option is inactive because Safari doesn't understand the content type (MIME type) of the page or doesn't think it's HTML.

To open Web Inspector, use "Inspect Element" after right-clicking an element on the page, or open the Web Inspector on another page and then navigate to this page.